# Is it possible to get a step by step to a Sum of a sequence?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n} {n^2} = -\frac{\pi^2}{12}
$$

`WolframAlpha["Sum[(-1)^n/n^2,{n,1,Infinity}]"]` is not working in this case.

The version I use is v12.0

Comment: Mathemaica v12.2 evalutes the expected result.

Comment: I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1gOM.png) on v12.2.0, Win7-x64.

Comment: On `V12.0.0` I get the same as @Syed showed

Comment: The sum of this series can be found through residues. I think this sum is implemented in Mathematica as a table value.

Comment: As a standard series homework exercise based on $\sum 1/n^2 = \pi^2/6$, you can derive your by splitting the even and odd terms, whose sums can be deduced from the given sum. If you want to deduce the first series, Google may be better than W|A, for it yielded a compendium: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1k2-basel-pro